# Prove $T$ is continuous if and only if there exist $k>0$ such that $\Vert T(x,y)\Vert\leq k\Vert x\Vert \Vert y\Vert.$

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, normed-spaces

Let $T$ be an operator defined on $X\times Y$, the product of normed space $X$ and $Y$ such that

(1) $T(x+x',y+y')=T(x,y)+T(x,y')+T(x',y)+T(x',y')$, $\forall (x,y)\in X\times Y, (x',y')\in X\times Y$.

(2) $T(\alpha x,\beta y)=\alpha\beta T(x,y), \forall (x,y)\in X\times Y$ with $\alpha$ and $\beta$ being scalars, i.e. $T$ is bilinear.

Show that $T$ is continuous if and only if there exist $k>0$ such that
$$\Vert T(x,y)\Vert\leq k\Vert x\Vert \Vert y\Vert.$$

I have tried as below.

($\Rightarrow)$ Given $T$ is continuous. Then $T$ is bounded, i.e if there exists $M > 0$ such that $\Vert (x,y)\Vert\leq 1$ implies $\Vert T(x,y)\Vert\leq M$. Now, we will prove $M=k\Vert x\Vert \Vert y\Vert$, with $k>0$. Let $\alpha,\beta>0$.
\begin{align}
\Vert T(x,y)\Vert
&=
\left\Vert T\left(\dfrac{\alpha}{\Vert x\Vert} x  \dfrac{\Vert x\Vert}{\alpha},\dfrac{\beta}{\Vert y\Vert} y \dfrac{\Vert y\Vert}{\beta}\right)\right\Vert\\
&=
\dfrac{\Vert x\Vert\Vert y\Vert}{\alpha\beta}\left  \Vert T\left(\dfrac{\alpha}{\Vert x\Vert} x  ,\dfrac{\beta}{\Vert y\Vert} y \right)\right\Vert\\
&\leq \dfrac{1}{\alpha\beta}\Vert x\Vert\Vert y\Vert
\end{align}

So, $k=\dfrac{1}{\alpha\beta}>0$.

($\Leftarrow)$ Given there exist $k>0$ such that
$$\Vert T(x,y)\Vert\leq k\Vert x\Vert \Vert y\Vert.$$

We will prove $T$ is continuous, i.e. we will show $T$ is bounded, if there exists $M > 0$ such that $\Vert (x,y)\Vert\leq 1$ implies $\Vert T(x,y)\Vert\leq M$.

Obviously, $k\Vert x\Vert \Vert y\Vert>0$. So, if we take $M=k\Vert x\Vert \Vert y\Vert$ then we have $\Vert T(x,y)\Vert\leq M$. Thus, $T$ is bounded operator then imply $T$ is continuous operator.

Does my proof is correct? I doubt it.
Any hint to prove it? I don't know the definition of continuous operator (not linear).

Comment: $T$ is not a linear map on $X \times Y$ so you cannot use the equivalence of continuity and boundedness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $T$ is continuous. Suppose there is no constant $k$ such that $\|(T(x,y)\| \leq k\|x\|\|y\|$. Then there exist $x_n$ and $y_n$ such that $\|(T(x_n,y_n)\| > n\|x_n\|\|y_n\|$. Let $u_n=\frac {x_n}{\sqrt n \|x\|_n}$ and $v_n=\frac {y_n}{\sqrt n \|y\|_n}$. Then $u_n \to 0$ and $v_n \to 0$. Hence $(u_n,v_n) \to (0,0)$ in $X \times Y$. By continuity of $T$ we get $T(u_n,v_n) \to (0,0)$ in $X \times Y$. This gives $\frac 1 { n \|x\|_n\|y\|_n}T(x_n,y_n) \to 0$ but $\|\frac 1 { n \|x\|_n\|y\|_n}T(x_n,y_n)\|>1$ for all $n$.

Converse: Suppose $\|(T(x,y)\| \leq k\|x\|\|y\|$. Let $(x_n,y_n) \to (x,y)$. Then $T(x_n,y_n)=T(x_n-x,y_n-y)+T(x,y)+T(x_n-x,y)+T(x_n,y_n-y)$. It is easy to check that this tends to $0$ from the inequality $\|(T(x,y)\| \leq k\|x\|\|y\|$ so $T$ is continuous.